# Beam splitter action on an entangled state : how do photons recombine?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-optics

**Context:**

Hello, I have to present [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.4137) in class next week. I encounter some difficulty with the [supplementary material](http://www.nature.com/nphoton/journal/v6/n11/extref/nphoton.2012.243-s1.pdf) at the end of section I.

There, the authors say they have a state of the form :
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
\alpha |g⟩ [|10⟩ + |01⟩] + \alpha |e⟩ [|10⟩ − |01⟩] + β|g⟩ [|10⟩ − |01⟩] + β|e⟩ [|10⟩ + |01⟩]
\end{equation}
Then, by passing this state through a 50:50 Beam Splitter, they obtain :
$$
α|g⟩|10⟩ + α|e⟩|01⟩ + β|g⟩|01⟩ + β|e⟩|10⟩
$$

**What I tried:**

However, I have difficulty seeing how to pass from the first state to the final one. In effect, I use the BS action :
$$
a^\dagger \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(c^\dagger + id^\dagger)
$$
$$
b^\dagger \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(ic^\dagger + d^\dagger)
$$

Let's say I take only the first term of the first expression I wrote above, I can rewrite it as follows :
$$
\alpha |g⟩ [|10⟩ + |01⟩] \equiv \alpha |g⟩ [(a^\dagger +b^\dagger)|0⟩_a|0⟩_b|0⟩_c|0⟩_d]
$$
which transforms under the action of the BS as :
$$
\alpha |g⟩ [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(c^\dagger + id^\dagger + ic^\dagger + d^\dagger)|0⟩_a|0⟩_b|0⟩_c|0⟩_d]
$$
This is quite different from what is expected from the final expression of the authors of the article, I should rather obtain something like :
$$
\alpha |g⟩ [c^\dagger|0⟩_a|0⟩_b|0⟩_c|0⟩_d]
$$
but I don't see how to get rid of the imaginaries in my former expression. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: '50/50 beamsplitter' is an ambiguous description. It could mean $\sqrt{1/2} \begin{bmatrix} 1&i\\i&1\end{bmatrix}$, the operation you described, or it could mean a Hadamard operation, $\sqrt{1/2} \begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}$, or really it could mean any other 2x2 unitary matrix where the entries all have equal magnitude. If the paper doesn't specify which, you'll have to figure it out from how they say things are acting.

Comment: Thank you very much @CraigGidney, using the Hadamard operation indeed seems to be working. I just have a weird  $2/\sqrt{2}$ constant in front but the general form seems to be respected. Do you have an idea how this constant could cancel ?

Comment: Gaining factors of $\sqrt 2$ is the equivalent of a sign-error when beam splitters are involved. Just recheck the math. In particular, make sure that all your operations are properly unitary.

Comment: I found that actually, I should use the $H_2$ Hadamard matrix (it's a 4x4) due to the fact that I have a tensor product of two photons states. The $H_2$ matrix  to be unitary, has a prefactor that is not $1/\sqrt{2}$ but rather $1/2$. Several links helped me : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/191344/what-operation-does-a-beam-splitter-apply and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55696/how-to-apply-a-hadamard-gate and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform#Definition

Comment: @Mary Ideally, you should write an answer to your post, explaining how to do it, and accept it, so it can serve as a future reference.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch sure, I was thinking about that and rephrasing my post so that it's more general, I will eventually. I just still need to clarify some little things for myself before that though. Anyway, any answer frome someone else is welcome too, you for example :)